# Global irreducible decomposition of an analytic set

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, complex-geometry

Let $M$ be a complex manifold (or a complex analityc space) and $Z$ be an analytic subset of $M$. By Noetherianity of the rings of germs of analytic functions at a point we know that $Z$ has finitely many irreducible germs at any $p \in Z$.

What about the "global" irreducible components?

How does one prove that a decomposition into irreducible analytic sets exists? 
(I have looked into Gunning and Rossi but couldn't find the relevant reference off-hand.)

I also have a related question: is it possible that an analytic set is connected but has infinitely many irreducible components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Yes, a connected  analytic space may have infinitely many irreducible components:

Take a disjoint family of projective lines $(P_i)_{i\in \mathbb N}$  with distinguished points $0_i $ and $1_i$.
Then identify each $1_{i}$ with $0_{i+1}$ .

b) A variant is to take in $\mathbb C^2$ the union of the line $y=0$ and the lines $x=i\; (i\in \mathbb Z)$ .  That subspace is connected and has infinitely many irreducible components.

c) The decomposition of an analytic subspace into irreducibles is proved on page 217 of  Łojasiewicz's *Introduction to Complex Analytic Geometry*

Comment: does this complex space properly embed as a closed analytic subspace into a complex space?

Comment: Yes : my space $X$  in a) is a closed analytic subspace of $X\times \mathbb C$. Anyway,  I have added  an example embeddable  into $\mathbb C^2$.

Comment: Dear Georges, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome, Dima.